# MCU or other boards with 100 MS/s ADC

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, adc, datalogger, data-acquisition

Are there any commercially available microcontrollers or SoC or SBC boards with integrated ADC that can do a sampling at 100 to 150MS/s. Looking for making a high speed and economic data capture system. Found this one from NXP : [LPC4370](https://www.nxp.com/design/microcontrollers-developer-resources/lpc-link2:OM13054) which can go upto 80MS/s.

If not what are the other options available.

Thanks in advace

Comment: Site rule: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: Please learn to research https://www.google.com/search?q=sbc+adc+%22150+MHz%22

Comment: https://www.digikey.be/nl/articles/analog-basics-part-3-pipeline-adcs-and-how-to-use-them https://www.ti.com/product/ADC12DJ5200RF?HQS=asc-dc-hsc-ADC12DJ5200RF-pr-pf-null-wwe https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/training-reference-material/Achieving-Maximum-Efficiency-from-a-Coin-Cell-Battery-Introducing-LPC55S69-MCU-based-E1-Board-from-OKdo.pdf https://www.scribd.com/document/442237377/A-Fully-Synthesized-All-Digital-VCO-Based-Analog-to-Digital-Converter

Comment: How many bits of ADC accuracy?  How many samples (continuously for hours, days, weeks) or in short bursts (how many consecutive data reads)?  You may be surprised at how quickly you run into read/write speed issues you'll have (on top of your sampling request).   Then, let us know how you will store or process the data collected.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @TonyStewartEE75, the article is good but out of scope for me and the google search led to sbc with 150MHz clock.

Comment: Thank you @GTElectronics. It's a continuous read application and is saved to a PC via USB. Planning to use a standalone system that could stream via ethernet to a sort of central hub.

Comment: Take a look at Red Pitaya. Not so much an MCU, more of an FPGA. But then your typical MCU can't do a whole lot with 100MS/s so you're gonna need the FPGA anyway.

Comment: Thank you @user_1818839, that was very helpful

Comment: Yes the Pitaya comes in different =flavours..  with a fast ADC for SDR app.  but if you search harder and ignore 150 CPU clock, there are more

Answer (score 1):

First you define BW and dynamic range & SNR specs, for ADC anti-aliasing filter.

Then define platform interface, power, cost etc [then find options.](https://www.scribd.com/document/442237377/A-Fully-Synthesized-All-Digital-VCO-Based-Analog-to-Digital-Converter%20%20https://www.digikey.be/nl/articles/analog-basics-part-3-pipeline-adcs-and-how-to-use-them%20https://www.ti.com/product/ADC12DJ5200RF?HQS=asc-dc-hsc-ADC12DJ5200RF-pr-pf-null-wwe%20https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/training-reference-material/Achieving-Maximum-Efficiency-from-a-Coin-Cell-Battery-Introducing-LPC55S69-MCU-based-E1-Board-from-OKdo.pdf)   Finding high performance budget solutions  demands engineering specs, patience and search towards sources of technology that meet your specific requirements. It may take a minute or 2 months. **The keywords search from your specs and awareness of [great distributor sources](https://www.banggood.com/buy/sdr-radio.html) are my secret to resolve your question.**